# How to display data from postgresql database to a dashboard in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to display my data stored in the database in odoo dashboard.
I have knowledge in python and sql but not at all familiar with odoo concepts.
I installed odoo and practised to create a basic module but could not update it in the app list.
I basically want to just display my data from the database in the dashboard in odoo.
How do I go about it??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general please provide more details .. What dashboard ? Odoo has a lot of apps that has dashboards on them and even has an app called Dashboard .. So be more specific

Odoo uses ORM methods to talk to postgreSQL database you don't need SQL to get your data. for example here is how to use the ORM methods

```
@api.depends('days_number')
def count_days(self):
    for rec in self:

        payslips = self.env['hr.payslip'].search([
            ('employee_id', '=', rec.employee_id.id)
        ])

        for payslip in payslips:
            for line in payslip.line_ids:
                if line.code == "NET":
                    net = line.amount
                    result = net / 30
                    total = rec.days_number * result
                    
        rec.amount = total
```

**hr.payslip** is a model in odoo witch is a table in database

**self.env** enables you to access all the tables in the database without the need of SQL

I hope you found the answer to your question .. if you need more information you can read the documentation in Odoo website to get you started [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/howtos/backend.html)

Comment: I am really new to this and getting confused while learning about odoo. I actually just want to display my data from my db in odoo . I have made a python script through which i am adding data to my db in postgresql.I want to display all that data on a dashboard like a summary  through filters , bar graphs,pie charts ,etc. Is this possible with odoo . Could you guide me with this. Thanks @Amr Abd-Alkrim